# Delete an image based on URL on WEB

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I cannot find a function like 'getReferenceFromUrl' on the web Firebase. I have stored a reference to the URL (and not the name of the image) for each item in my database.

Is there any workaround to get the reference on the image with the URL?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yep, it's in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#create_a_reference), maybe a little hidden.

```
// Create a reference to the file to delete
var desertRef = firebase.storage().refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com...')

// Delete the file
desertRef.delete().then(function() {
  // File deleted successfully
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```